# How does Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr do the type conversion

Tags: c++, com, wrl

I am getting an error for the following code:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("9DAD7B57-D626-4AB6-B844-910DE46DAC01")) IHen : public IUnknown
{
    virtual void Cluck() = 0;
};

struct __declspec(uuid("8FEA0426-91CA-4264-AAC5-544A7544E628")) IHen2 : IHen
{
    virtual void __stdcall Forage() = 0;
};

struct Hen : RuntimeClass<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>,
    IHen,
    IHen2>
{
    Hen(){}
    ~Hen(){}

    void Cluck() {}
    void Forage() {}
};

int main()
{
    ComPtr<IHen> hen;
    hen = Make<Hen>();
}
```

> Error C2440   '': cannot convert from 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<Hen>' to 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IHen>

If I change the `ComPtr` to:

```
ComPtr<IHen2> hen;
```

It works.

I am trying to understand why. How can it convert to immediate base, but not to its base?

Comment: The error is quite clear: a `ComPtr<Hen>` (what's returned from `Make`) is not a `ComPtr<IHen>`. Only `QueryInterface` can get you a COM interface reference, so you can fix it like this: `auto henCls = Make<Hen>(); henCls->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(hen.GetAddressOf()));`

Comment: But then how does it work with `ComPtr<IHen2> hen;`? There is no error if my `hen` is a `IHen2` com pointer.

Comment: `IHen2` derives from `IHen`, just remove the `IHen` in the list of `RuntimeClass` implemented interfaces as it creates an ambiguity.

Comment: Look in the Output window for an explanation of the error.  struct IHen2 : virtual IHen {} resolves the ambiguity as well, not sure if it is valid.

Comment: @SimonMourier your solution works. But now I am confused. Because I see a lot of places in my codebaes where it is listing all of the interfaces in the `RuntimeClass`. These interfaces have linear inheritance like in my example and all of them are listed in `RuntimeClass`. So what should be correct way to use `RuntimeClass` and `ComPtr`?

Comment: I can't speculate on your other "lot of places" where it seems to work. You have to make sure there's no ambiguity in the final v-table layout. If there is, there's no implicit cast possible.